# both information

Tags: grammaticality

*I have decided to log both these details.*

I have used the above statement on Stackoverflow, but I was wondering if it is correct to say the following:

*I have decided to log both information.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not. "Information" is not plural, so you cannot apply "both" to it.

Now, if you had said "I have decided to log both data", we might have some debate over "data".

Comment: Could you apply 'both' if you would say “both pieces of information“? Would it sound odd?

Comment: Yes, "both pieces" is correct.